# What is the Difference between "Internal" and "External" Source Systems in Data Warehousing?

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, etl, maintenance

I am reading about data warehousing and I run into the concept of ***internal*** and ***external*** source systems.

> Data are extracted from various *internal* and *external* source system files and databases.

[image: Here is a supplementary figure of the concept]

I couldn't clearly distinguish between the concept of *internal* and *external*.

Any explanation of the key difference?

Thank you,

Comment: Any data source outside of your system would be considered external. Could be another similar DBMS, different DBMS, flat file, file share, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You could get data from data providers - for example, geoip data from Maxmind, rating data from Moody's, device data from BlueCava. Those are all external systems. Systems used by the organization are internal systems.